# Variables de entorno en .bat

Tags: cmd

queria saber como hacer para crear una variable PATH y otra CLASSPATH en las variables de entorno pero del usuario , NO DEL SISTEMA en un archivo .bat en el caso de que no esten creadas

Answer (score 1):

La variable `PATH` siempre esta definida pero si la defines para el usuario 
se toma esta definicion + la del sistema; si lo quieres guardar fuera del .bat ya es otra cosa solo funciona para lo que ejecutes dentro de el:

```
IF NO DEFINED PATH SET PATH='YO SIEMPRE ESTOY DEFINIDO'
IF NO DEFINED CLASSPATH SET CLASSPATH=OK
ejecutar X...Y y Z
```